# LNK2005-Error when declaring a function in a .hpp-File

Tags: c++, function, sfml, lnk2005

I'm building a program, and need a function to check if the mouse is on an object. I wrote the function and created a new .hpp-File, because multiple Files in my project will use the function. The File is called `HitboxDetec.hpp`. The function I wrote in it looks like this:

```
bool isClicked(sf::Sprite* Sprite, sf::RenderWindow* pW)
{
    int MOUSE_X = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*pW).x;
    int MOUSE_Y = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*pW).y;

    if (MOUSE_X >= Sprite->getPosition().x &&
        MOUSE_X <= Sprite->getPosition().x + Sprite->getPosition().x + 500 &&
        MOUSE_Y >= Sprite->getPosition().y &&
        MOUSE_Y <= Sprite->getPosition().y + Sprite->getPosition().y + 500)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

I included the needed libraries etc. and the code works (I tested it by declaring the function in my .cpp-File).

In my .cpp File I included the `CookieDetec.hpp`-File, and called it with

```
if(isClicked(pSprite, pW)) {Stuff}
```

When I compile my program, it just gives me a LNK2005-Error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

LNK2005 is for:

```
The given symbol, displayed in its decorated form, was multiply defined.
```

if you defined your function in header file then it might be included in multiple translation units. To prevent multiple definitions mark this function as inline:

```
inline bool isClicked(sf::Sprite* Sprite, sf::RenderWindow* pW)
^^^^^^
```